# Xcode has lost some simulators in the latest upgrade

Tags: xcode

Ok, so Ive just noticed that Xcode has lost a number of simulators from the run dropdown.

Have already tried the add simulators button but all the simulators are already in the popup box list and adding one just adds a duplicate to the popup list (but not to the run dropdown).
Ive tried downloading some simulators but that just gives me a duplicate on the operating system of the few simulators that Ive already got.
Ive tried re-installing Xcode but a new project out of the box has the reduced list too!
My OLD projects still show the full list.

Im at a loss as to how to get them back.

On a final note, Ive considered the small list I have and can see that the simulators that are there pretty much cover the range of screen sizes that are used. Could this be done on purpose in the latest version?????

Here are the ones I do get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0c0R.png)

Im using 13.6 or 13.5 as deployment target but have tried others down to 12 and get the same issue.

Comment: Which versions are you missing, and what are you app's deployment targets?

Comment: thanks for replying. Have edited the question to include this :)

Comment: “Have edited the question to include this” No, you haven’t. Give an example of a “missing” simulator.

Comment: When your deployment target is 13.5, you won't see any simulator targets other than those using 13.5 and 13.6 - that's a feature.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks everyone. I have figured it out based on your replies.

When I installed the 13.5 simulators (it took forever and was like 3G) for some reason it din't add some simulators to the dropdown (for instance no X, or 7 or 6).

From what has been said here I now went back to the 'add additional simulators..' button and added those missing devices **with the appropriate iOS**. This has fixed it.
Its odd though that when I select a different iOS for the target it does not change the simulator list to match, for instance if I select 12.2 it does not change the dropdown list to match (which is where my confusion was coming from) I have to go the simulators and manually change them....